# Overcome SubQuery Returned More Than 1 Result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, subquery

I found this syntax already answered to a diff question, but I am getting the error of

> More than 1 result returned

what do I need to alter in my syntax in order to defeat this error?

```
Declare @ONE Table
(
    employee varchar(250)
    ,eod int
)

Declare @Two Table
(
    employee varchar(250)
    ,amtpaid decimal(10,2)
)

Insert Into @One (employee, eod) VALUES
('Frank',   '1122')
,('Frank',  '1188')
,('Bill',   '1100')
,('Larry', '1199')
,('Bill',   '2211')
,('Jerry',  '3311')
,('Jerry',  '3322')
,('Stan',   '3388')
,('Stan',   '3300')
,('Larry',  '3377')

INSERT INTO @Two (employee, amtpaid) VALUES
('Frank', '11.11'),('Bill', '10.10')
,('Larry', '44.44'),('Jerry', '20.32')
,('Stan', '100.33')

SELECT a.employee
    ,[EOD] = b.eod
    ,[Paid] = CASE 
        WHEN b.eod = (
                SELECT min(b.eod)
                FROM @Two
                WHERE b.employee=a.employee
                )
            THEN COALESCE((
                        SELECT TOP 1 SUM(ISNULL(amtpaid, 0))
                        FROM @Two b
                        WHERE a.employee = b.employee
                        ), 0)
        ELSE 0
        END
FROM @One b
INNER JOIN @Two a
ON a.employee = b.employee
GROUP BY a.employee, b.eod, b.employee
ORDER BY a.employee ASC
```

**EDIT**
My desired output is like below - amtpaid showing for only 1 employeename not all of them

```
Employee    EOD Paid
Bill    1100    10.10
Bill    2211    0.00
Frank   1122    11.11
Frank   1188    0.00
Jerry   3311    20.32
Jerry   3322    0.00
Larry   1199    44.44
Larry   3377    0.00
Stan    3388    0.00
Stan    3300    100.33
```

Comment: What exactly is this query trying to do? I'm sure there's a less convoluted way

Comment: @ypercube - I want to show amtpaid for only one employee.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: Not really. Can you edit the question and add the expected output?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - see edit, I added desired output.  I want paid to only be updated for one employee name.  Not paid showed multiple times for each employee name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `GROUP BY`, no subqueries needed. The answer assumes that `@Two` has only one row per `employee`:

```
SELECT 
    a.employee,
    [EOD] = a.eod,
    [Paid] = CASE WHEN a.eod = MIN(a.eod) OVER (PARTITION BY a.employee)
                 THEN b.amtpaid
                 ELSE 0
             END
FROM 
    @One a
    JOIN @Two b
    ON  a.employee = b.employee ;
```

Another way would be to use window functions and a left join:

```
SELECT 
    a.employee,
    [EOD] = a.eod,
    [Paid] = COALESCE(b.amtpaid, 0)
FROM 
    ( SELECT a.employee, a.eod,
             rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.employee
                                     ORDER BY a.eod)
      FROM @One AS a
    ) AS a
    LEFT JOIN @Two b
    ON  a.employee = b.employee 
    AND a.rn = 1 ;
```

which would be easier to modify if `@Two` has more than one rows per employee and we want the sum:

```
SELECT 
    a.employee,
    [EOD] = a.eod,
    [Paid] = COALESCE(b.amtpaid, 0)
FROM 
    ( SELECT a.employee, a.eod,
             rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.employee
                                     ORDER BY a.eod)
      FROM @One AS a
    ) AS a
    OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT amtpaid = SUM(b.amtpaid)
      FROM @Two b
      WHERE a.employee = b.employee 
        AND a.rn = 1
    ) AS b ;
```

Comment: How would i handle if @Two has more than one row per employee?

Comment: and you want the sum to appear in one row, as before?

Comment: Yes - still only one row showing the sum.

Comment: Is it quicker to use a `Outer Apply` than using a sub-query?

Comment: It's similar. We could keep the LEFT JOIN and add a GROUP BY (instead of the OUTER APPLY).

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to like below. I assumed you are trying to add `amtpaid` value of #Two to Minimum of `eod` record of #ONE employee

```
SELECT  a.employee
    ,[EOD] = A.eod 
    ,[Paid] = CASE A.EOD
        WHEN (
                SELECT MIN(A1.EOD)
                FROM #ONE A1
                WHERE A1.employee = A.employee
                )
            THEN (
                    SELECT SUM(B2.amtpaid)
                    FROM #Two B2
                    WHERE A.employee = B2.employee
                    )

    ELSE 0 END
FROM #ONE A
```

The result will be

```
+----------+------+--------+
| employee | EOD  |  Paid  |
+----------+------+--------+
| Frank    | 1122 |  11.11 |
| Frank    | 1188 |   0.00 |
| Bill     | 1100 |  10.10 |
| Larry    | 1199 |  44.44 |
| Bill     | 2211 |   0.00 |
| Jerry    | 3311 |  20.32 |
| Jerry    | 3322 |   0.00 |
| Stan     | 3388 |   0.00 |
| Stan     | 3300 | 100.33 |
| Larry    | 3377 |   0.00 |
+----------+------+--------+
```